# Magento 1.x site gives me an error message about Fatal error

Tags: magento-1, fatal-error

I get this when I go to my site:

Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 946`

I have done anything on it today.

May I ask for direction?

Comment: tak the backup of this file and replace original file and check

Comment: For those magically appearing errors that weren't there yesterday and aren't the result of making code changes, or module installations, have you tried clearing the cache? Sounds like a config cache corruption issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to code `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` on line 946

```
$modules = $this->getNode('modules')->children();
```

In your one of module have missing modules node.

go to `app/etc/modules` and locate the module declaration file. It'll follow the naming convention [Package]_[Modulename].xml

In that xml file,For disable module find the `<active>true</active>` node and change it to `<active>false</active>`

Disable module one by one and check which module have error.

Answer (score 0):

change following in **app/Mage.php**

```
public static function getRoot()
{
    return self::$_appRoot;
}
```

to

```
public static function getRoot()
{
    if(empty(self::$_appRoot))
            self::setRoot();
    return self::$_appRoot;
}
```

this is working fine in almost all upgrade issues